# Power BI column calculation issue

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a set of vales in Power BI that look like this:

[image]

When I try and divide the values using the following:

Value 3 = Table1[Value1] / Table2[Value2]

Value 3 = DIVIDE(Table1[Value1], Table2[Value2],0)

I keep getting the following result:

[image]

For some reason, it is assuming both value are equal.
I have also tried a combination of averaging the values on both side but seem to get stuck in the same loop.

Am I missing something obvious as I am new to this?

Thanks!

Comment: can give sample for table 2

Comment: I have 2 tables, the first is a reference table which lists
Year, Role, Total
This is for capacity.

The second table is a list which contains a number of 'withdrawals' which I am totalling up.

The idea is that value 3 will be the result of Value 1 (from a reference table) minus Value 2 (Sum of withdrawals)

Comment: Please clarify, are you creating a calculated column or a measure?

Comment: The reason you have this problem (most likely) is because your data model is built incorrectly. However, from the information you have provided it's impossible to see what specifically is wrong with it. It will be helpful is you paste your data model diagram (or at least its part that involves both tables and their relations),